# UINavigationController show segue fails?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, uistoryboard

I have three views in my IB, which are embedded in a navigation controller, which is embedded in a tab Controller. Every segue works. However, when I embed the last view in its own navigation controller and run the app, instead of being shown from the previous view, it is now presented modally, the tab Bar does not appear on the view, and all the navigation attributes that are supposed to be passed on aren't. Here is how the IB looks:

[image]

from my migration to swift 2, this was the only code change in my custom navigation controller class:

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = false
    self.delegate = self
}`
```

i was forced to unwrap the gesture by adding "!":

`override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

```
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!.enabled = false
    self.delegate = self
}`
```

Now I never had this issue in Xcode 6, iOS 8.. Why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Why are you embedding the last scene in its own navigation controller?

Comment: i have a special transition navigation controller class I created for that controller @Paulw11

Comment: it had no issue in iOS 8 and Xcode 6 @Paulw11

Comment: Please look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650004/no-back-button-in-swift-2 maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue before. Although my setup is not as similar as yours but I got a similar output. So, what I did is, I changed the segue type between the last navigation controller and the second table view controller to **push**(which is being deprecated). But this still works well in iOS 8. I am not sure it will work in your case.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: push is not accepted at all in iOS 9, which I'm on. it threw an exception.. check updated question, added some code that i had to change during the migration to swift 2