# No back button in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I updated my project to Swift 2.0. When I move from the `UITableViewController` to the `UIViewController`, Navigation Item doesn't show back button. Each controller has UINavigationController and I use the show segue.

This code when I move to other controller

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        if searchPredicate == nil {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("listenMusic", sender: self)
        } else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("oneSound", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "listenMusic" {

        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer != nil {
            if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer.playing {
                (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer.stop()
            }
        }
            let playerVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayMusicViewController

            // variant the second
            let curRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
            playerVC.arrayOfMP3 = listOfMP3Files
            playerVC.currentRow = curRow
//            println(listOfMP3Files[curRow])
      } else if segue.identifier == "oneSound" {
        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer != nil {
           if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer.playing {
                (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).mainAudioPlayer.stop()
                }
            }
        let playerFromOne = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! PlayerFromOneTable
        let currentIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
        let currentTrackPass = arraySearchResults[currentIndex]
//        var currentIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        playerFromOne.currentTrack = currentTrackPass
//        NSLog("Current track passs %@", currentTrackPass)
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

I created new empty project and made simple segue from `UIViewController` to the second `UIViewController` and I got the same.
I observed that new `UIViewController` appear from bottom and not from the right side.

Comment: You have the navigation controller in the wrong place. It should be `NavigationController -> TableViewController -> MusicPlayerController`

Comment: @Fogmeister UITableViewController also has UINavigationController

Comment: Then you don't need a second one. Only one navigation controller is needed for most purposes.

Comment: In fact, the second navigation controller is probably actually causing this problem. It is the first navigation controller that needs to pop back but it can't because you have a second navigation controller on top of it. You only need one navigation controller for the entire app (for most cases). You push and pop onto that one navigation controller. You don't add multiple navigation controllers. This can be read from any tutorial or possibly also the documentation about navigation controller.

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you. You very much helped me. When I use Xcode 6 and Swift 1 or Swift 1.2 I didn't have this problem and I didn't  know that you wrote above. I now know it thanks to you!

Comment: My question may to close